# Issue with a method for a library of objects

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that creates a library of different books, I have set a number of copies for each item in the library and every time I check out an Item I want it to deduct 1 copy from only the particular object I check out but instead it takes a copy away from all the objects. not sure how to fix the problem.

```
public abstract class Item{
  private int identify;
  private String title;
  private int copies;

  public Item(){
    identify=0;
    title="N/A";
    copies=0;
  }
  public Item(int id, int copy, String t){
    identify=id;
    copies=copy;
    title=t;
  }
  public void setIdentificationNumber(int id){
    identify = id;
  }
  public void setTitle(String t){
    title=t;
  }
  public void setNumberCopies(int num){
    copies=num;
  }
  public int getIdentificationNumber(){
    return identify;
  }
  public String getTitle(){
    return title;
  }
  public int getNumberCopies(){
    return copies;
  }
  public void checkOut(){
    if(copies>0){
      copies-=1;
      System.out.println("You have checked out "+title+". Thank You");
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("All copies of "+title+" are checked out!");
    }
  }
  public void checkIn(){
    copies+=1;
  }
}
```

The problem may also be in my client method I have posted the code for that as well below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Library{
  static String title;
  static String author;
  static int id;
  static int copies;
  static String date;
  static Book[] database = new Book[100];
  static int count=0;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int i;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
      addBook();
      System.out.println("would you like to add another book?");
      i=s.nextInt();
    }while(i == 0);
    database[0].viewDetails();
    database[1].viewDetails();
    checkingOut();
    database[0].viewDetails();
    database[1].viewDetails();
  }
  public static void addBook(){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the title of the book you want to add to the collection");
    title=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the author of the book you want to add to the collection");
    author=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the publishing date of the book you want to add to the collection");
    date=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the book you want to add to the collection");
    id=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the the number of copies that will be added into the collection");
    copies=s.nextInt();

    Book Book1 = new Book(date, author, copies, id, title);
    database[count] = Book1;
    count++;
  }
  public static void checkingOut(){
    boolean found=false;
    int idSearch;
    int i=0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the book you want to check out");
    idSearch=s.nextInt();
    while(i<database.length && found!=true){
      if(database[i].getIdentificationNumber() == idSearch){
        found = true;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if(found==true){
      database[i].checkOut();
      System.out.println("There are "+database[i].getNumberCopies()+" copies left");
    }
    else{System.out.println("There is no book with that ID number!");}
  }
}
```

In my addBook method I create a new object called book1 every time I make a new book, so I think that it may be changing all of the book objects every time I add a book. I'm not really sure of a better way to write the method.

here is my method for book also

```
public class Book extends WrittenItem{
  public Book(){
    super();
  }
  public Book(String date, String a, int copy, int id, String t){
    super(a, date, copy, id, t);

  }
  public void viewDetails(){
    System.out.println("ID: "+getIdentificationNumber()+"\nTitle: "+getTitle()+"\nAuthor: "+getAuthor()+" Date written: "+getDate()+"\nCopies available: "+getNumberCopies());
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should you add `break;` after this line `found = true;` ?

Comment: does `Book` extend `Item`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't 100% tell from your code, but I'm assuming `Book extends Item`.  In that case, try something like this for `Book` constructor

```
public class Book extends Item {
    String author;
    String date;

    public Book(String date, String author, int copies, int id, String title) {
        super(id, copies, title); // Item constructor matches this super() call
                                  // public Item(int id, int copy, String t)
        this.author = author;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

You want `Book` to have the same `copies` at Item. So when you `checkOut()`, the Item number equals you input from the `Book` constructor.  If you don't put the `super()` in the constructor, your `Item` `copies` will remain 0 and you will always get `System.out.println("All copies of "+title+" are checked out!");` because `copies` is never `> 0`.

Comment: Yes book does extend item, I have super(id, copies, title); in the constructor of book.

Comment: So let me get this correct.  Your basic problem is that , you are getting this output `System.out.println("All copies of "+title+" are checked out!");` instead of this one `System.out.println("You have checked out "+title+". Thank You");`? Am I correct. or is there something else that is going wrong?

Comment: You want to show a snippet of your `WrittenItem`, just the relevant code, constructor included.

Comment: @Julien Kerr, and no you do not have `super(id, copies, title)` in your book constructor.  Your `book` constructor has a `super(5 args)`

Answer (score 0):

If your book is something like this,

```
public class Book extends Item {

    private String date;
    private String author;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String date, String author, int copies, int id, String title) {
        super(id, copies, title);
        this.author = author;
        this.date = date;
    }

    void viewDetails() {
        System.out.println("date:" + date + " author:" + author + " copies:" + getNumberCopies() + " id:" + getIdentificationNumber() + " title:" + getTitle());
    }
}
```

Then your code should work fine, as i've tested, if you also add a *break* in your `checkingOut()` method,

```
public static void checkingOut() {
        boolean found = false;
        int idSearch;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the ID number of the book you want to check out");
        idSearch = s.nextInt();
        while (i < database.length && found != true) {
            if (database[i].getIdentificationNumber() == idSearch) {
                found = true;
                break; //add this
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (found == true) {
            database[i].checkOut();
            System.out.println("There are " + database[i].getNumberCopies() + " copies left");
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is no book with that ID number!");
        }
    }
```